# Why has Swift 1.2 broken inheritance of UIDynamicAnimator's init(collectionViewLayout:)?

Tags: swift

In Swift 1.1 and before, this was legal:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewLayout()
class MyDynamicAnimator : UIDynamicAnimator {}
let anim2 = MyDynamicAnimator(collectionViewLayout:layout)
```

In Swift 1.2, it refuses to compile. Why?

I can work around the problem by overriding `init(collectionViewLayout:)` to do nothing but call super:

```
class MyDynamicAnimator : UIDynamicAnimator {
    override init(collectionViewLayout:UICollectionViewLayout) {
        super.init(collectionViewLayout:collectionViewLayout)
    }
}
```

But that seems kind of nutty. If I can override it, why can't I just inherit it?

**NOTE:** I'm guessing that the reason for this problem *might* be that UIDynamicAnimator's `init(collectionViewLayout:)` is a designated initializer declared in an extension, which is illegal according to Swift. But it isn't illegal according to Cocoa, so surely it still needs to be inherited! This breakage feels like a bug to me... It should be no business of mine, as programmer, to be caught up by the technicalities of where an initializer happens to be declared in the structure of the API header.

[EDIT: I've filed a bug report on this with Apple, but have received no reply. The situation remains inexplicable to me. I am not persuaded that this has anything to do with the `extension`, either. It seems just wrong.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug, as is shown by the fact that it is fixed in Xcode 7 / iOS 9.